# Replacing dead mower battery with modern battery

Tags: battery, lawn-mower

I have a Black & Decker PowerSwap mower I bought perhaps 7 years ago. Its a battery-operated model that came with 2 60V "Max" batteries (it only needs 1 to operate).

It otherwise still works great, but this summer one of the batteries died (won't take a charge anymore), and at the end of the summer the other one went too.

I tried pricing replacement 60V Black & Decker batteries, but they are north of $200 each. The mower itself can be had for $400. I tried ordering a cheap 3rd party replacement for more like $100, but it never arrived.

So at first now I'm thinking new mower. But then I notice that a lot of battery-operated mowers these days don't come with batteries, but let you pick up your choice from their manufacturer line of batteries, presumably trading off capacity for cost.

So I'm wondering if this is *a thing* for this old mower too. Can other Black & Decker batteries be used in Black & Decker mowers like this one? Or should one expect that batteries have to match the Voltage and Amperage of the original batteries when buying replacements?

Comment: A lot of times will be if the battery fits in the battery box/compartment.  The voltage/amperage is more how it works, slower/faster, shorter/longer time.

Comment: What about getting the existing batteries refurbished?

Comment: @SolarMike - One of my kids mentioned that too. I'd never heard of that as an option. Where can I read up on doing that?

Comment: A google search may be a good start - check for businesses in your area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Other" B+D batteries (ie, 20v or something other than 60v) won't work in your mower. Other brand 60v batteries (Dewalt) are very unlikely to work, and they cost a fortune anyway, so you wouldn't be ahead. You don't need to match the amp-hour number but you do have to match the voltage.

Getting the existing batteries refurbished, as @solarmike suggested, is an option, but you might find that the cost of cells in low quantities and the skill required to solder/desolder makes that prohibitive. (The preferred method of soldering to cells is spot welding, so as not to mess up the new cells.)

One possibility, albeit unlikely, is that you might find an adapter that converts from your slide-on base to a more common/cheaper/more readily available battery. At a glance I didn't find anything, but I didn't look that hard, either.

So I'd say you've got 3 choices: buy new B+D batteries, or buy knockoff batteries for cheap (knowing that it's a gamble, as some of those are crap), or buy a modern mower with readily available batteries.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. The thing that bothers me about buying a new mower is, 5+ years from now am I going to be in the same position doing the same damn thing? Should I just resign myself to $400 rechargeable mowers being a 5 year purchase?

Comment: That is kind of the problem with batteries... they have a finite lifespan, and are expensive to replace. If you could find a mower with a battery platform that was useful to you in other ways (drill, saw, impact driver, etc), then that might amortize the pain a little bit. There's always gas (which has its own problems, but not a 5 year lifespan)...

Comment: Battery cells like this **don’t** get soldered, they get spot-welded. Huge difference.

Comment: Bought a cheap knock-off battery. Charged it up and did a run, and it seemed to work, but of course since its winter now, can't really stress test it. We'll see how it holds up this summer.